# How do I link a cell in Google Spreadsheets to a cell in another document?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I have a monthly spreadsheet that relies on figures from the previous month. I'd like to import these values dynamically rather than cutting and pasting them. Is this possible? How do I do it?

Comment: This question was posted during the private beta of this site.  It was closed because it doesn't meet the [current quality standards](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error) and locked for historical reasons as nowadays it looks to be a trivial question.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

`IMPORTRANGE()` appears to be the function you want.

From the [Google spreadsheets function list](https://support.google.com/drive/table/25273?page=table.cs&rd=2):

> Google Spreadsheets lets you reference
>   another workbook in the spreadsheet
>   that you're currently editing by using
>   the ImportRange function. ImportRange
>   lets you pull one or more cell values
>   from one spreadsheet into another. To
>   create your own ImportRange formulas,
>   enter =importRange(spreadsheet-key,
>   range). For languages where comma is
>   used for decimal separation, use a
>   semicolon instead of a comma to
>   separate arguments in your formula.
>
> Spreadsheet-key is a STRING which is
>   the key value from the spreadsheet
>   URL.
>
> Range is a STRING representing the
>   range of cells you want to import,
>   optionally including the sheet name
>   (defaults to first sheet). You can
>   also use a range name if you prefer.
>
> Given that the two arguments are
>   STRINGs, you need to enclose them in
>   quotes or refer to cells which have
>   string values in them.
>
> For example:
>
> =importrange("abcd123abcd123", "sheet1!A1:C10") "abcd123abcd123" is
>   the value in the "key=" attribute on
>   the URL of the target spreadsheet and
>   "sheet1!A1:C10" is the range which is
>   desired to be imported.
>
> =importrange(A1,B1) Cell A1 contains the string ABCD123ABCD123 and cell B1
>   contains sheet1!A1:C10
>
> Note: In order to use ImportRange, you
>   need to have been added as a viewer or
>   collaborator to the spreadsheet from
>   which ImportRange is pulling the data.
>   Otherwise, you'll get this error:
>   "#REF! error: The requested
>   spreadsheet key, sheet title, or cell
>   range was not found."

"key" is, of course, the string in the URL for the spreadsheet that matches to the `key=` parameter.

I just tested it by creating two spreadsheets. In cell A1 of the first, I put a string. In cell A1 of the second, I put `=importRange("tgR2P4UTz_KT0Lc270Ijb_A","A1")` and it displayed the string from the first spreadsheet. (Your key will obviously be different.)

(The format of the function may depend on your locale. In France the formula is not valid with a comma, so you'll need to replace it with a semi-colon: `=importRange("tgR2P4UTz_KT0Lc270Ijb_A";"A1")`)

*NOTES:*

1. Google currently sets a hard limit of 50 "cross-workbook reference formulas" per spreadsheet. Source: [Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides size limits](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603). *(h/t [JJ Rohrer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/49146/jj-rohrer))*
2. The "new" Google Spreadsheet (soon to be the standard) removes the 50 limit of 50 "cross-workbook reference formulas ([Google Support](http://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093340)) *(h/t [Jacob Jan Tuinstra](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/29140/jacob-jan-tuinstra))*
3. In the "new" Google Sheets you also use the entire URL as the key ([Google Support](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)) *(h/t [Punchlinern](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/29712/punchlinern))*

Comment: +1 Whoa! I didn't realize there was an in-line version. The other option is to use Google Apps scripting. Create a function that uses SpreadsheetApp.openById([ID]).getRange() and set a local range with that.

Comment: It might be worth noting that you'll be limited to 50 of these (per spreadsheet?) (a hard Google limit): https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en

Comment: @JJRohrer: Good catch. I'll update my answer to include that.

Comment: In the new Google Spreadsheet (soon to be the standard), the 50 limit has been removed: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093340?hl=en

Comment: Also, in the new Google Sheets you use the [entire URL](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en) as key. 
Furthermore, you're prompted to grant access to the requested sheet when you first enter the function.

Comment: Also be aware that you need to update your imports after you docs are upgraded - their IDs may change and your will be in permission granting wait mode forever.

Comment: as probably expected, the link here isn't two way. meaning whereas when you link to another sheet, moving the cell around, updates the link; that doesn't happen here. The link simply breaks if you move it around.

Answer (score 36):

FYI if you want to reference another sheet within that other spreadsheet, the sheet name should NOT be re-quoted:

use

`=importRange("tgR2P4UTz_KT0Lc270Ijb_A","Sheet Name!A1:A10")`

instead of

`=importRange("tgR2P4UTz_KT0Lc270Ijb_A","'Sheet Name'!A1:A10")`

Comment: Thanks. You should add this as a comment to other answer or even just edit that answer.

Answer (score 10):

In the new interface, you should simply be able to type `=` in the cell, then just go to the other sheet and pick the cell you want. If you want to do it manually, or are using the old interface, you can simply do `=Sheet1!A1`, where `Sheet1` is the name of the sheet, and `A1` is the cell on that sheet you care about. This is identical to Microsoft Excel.

Comment: if the sheetname has whitespaces in it, use 'This Other Sheet'!A1

Comment: What about from an entirely different document, as I asked in the question?

Comment: @jeff Sorry; you didn't mention "document" in the body, and for some reason, in my head, I thought "sheet."  As far as I know, you can't dynamically link to another *document*. But you could use multiple sheets, rather than multiple documents, at which point you could do what I suggested. This is how I run my own monthly finances, for precisely this reason.

Comment: It's okay :) I know there's a way to do it as I've actually done it myself, but I've forgotten and I can't find the sheet I did it in.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question posted - it is talking about other sheets in the same document.

Answer (score 4):

I found this syntax using Insert -> Define new range

#### RANGE FOR REFERENCING OTHER SPREADSHEET:

> Whole A column: 'Spreadsheet With Spaces in the name'!A:A
>
> Whole B column: 'Spreadsheet With Spaces in the name'!B:B

etc.

Then you can use it as:

```
=COUNTIF('First Page'!B:B, "valueToMatch")
```

Comment: Is this also possible for referencing outside the spreadsheet?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra what do you mean 'outside' the spreadsheet?

Comment: Well, the `IMPORTRANGE` function can _import_ data from **another** spreadsheet. Setting ranges is only meant (possible) within a spreadsheet. That's what I meant with outside.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question posted - it's only describing how to refer to another sheet in the same document.

Comment: @brendan use `IMPORTRANGE` as Jacob said.

Answer (score 2):

here is how I did it (reimplemented 'importrange()'):

- open the script editor ("tools" -> "scripts" -> "script editor")
- provide a function like this (without any checks, this has to be improved but you get the general idea):

```
function REMOTEDATA(inKey, inRange) {

  var outData;  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(inKey);

  if (ss) {
     outData = ss.getRange(inRange).getValues();
  }

  return outData;
}
```

- use this formula like this in your spreadsheet:

```
=SUM(REMOTEDATA("key", "SheetName!A1:A10"))
```

"key" is the key of the document, you find it in the "key=xyz" parameter of the document URL.

the documentation for '[spreadsheet services](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/scripts/service_spreadsheet.html)' provides more information on the topic.

Comment: What would be the advantage of implementing this yourself rather than using the existing function?

Comment: @Jeff Yates: none, i just implemented it without knowing importrange(). sportsmanship, you know? all in the way of just- because-i-can :)

Comment: unfortunately spreadsheet custom functions cannot open anymore other spreadsheets using `SpreadsheetApp.openById()` or `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl()` -> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to import values from one spreadsheet to another dynamically in Google Sheets. To do this, you can use the `IMPORTRANGE` function.

The `IMPORTRANGE` function allows you to import a range of cells from one spreadsheet to another. You can use it to import values from a previous month's spreadsheet into your current monthly spreadsheet.

Here is the syntax for the `IMPORTRANGE` function:

```
IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_url, range_string)
```

- `spreadsheet_url`: The URL of the spreadsheet that you want to import data from.
- `range_string`: The range of cells that you want to import, in A1 notation. For example, "Sheet1!A1:B5" would import the range of cells from A1 to B5 on Sheet1 of the source spreadsheet.

Here is an example of how you can use the `IMPORTRANGE` function to import values from a previous month's spreadsheet:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fZwYzY4H5Vuq4vQP7g-kTdF1Xn3nqr2_KjtSlB", "Sheet1!A1:B5")
```

This formula will import the range of cells from A1 to B5 on Sheet1 of the source spreadsheet (located at the URL provided) into the current spreadsheet.

Keep in mind that the `IMPORTRANGE` function only works if the source spreadsheet is shared with you, and you have permission to access it. You will also need to authorize the import by following the prompts that appear when you enter the formula.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

As the question did not specify how the data is to be used, it is worth noting that `IMPORTRANGE` can be used anywhere a range can be used, for example, as the `range` argument to a `VLOOKUP`:

```
=VLOOKUP($C24,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP1234/edit#gid=0","Product List!$C$3:$H$31"), 4, false)
```

(fake spreadsheet URL for demo purposes).

Answer (score -2):

I did it the very easy way by using Query, for example, I have 2 sheets ABC  and XYZ and I want to import range from A1 to C30 from Abc into XYZ, click the cell where you want the range to appear and write this:

`=QUERY(ABC!A1:C30)`

Note: If your sheet name has spaces then, of course, you write this:

`=QUERY('ABC 1'!A1:C30)`

Comment: The OP asked how to import cells from another _document_. Can `QUERY` do that?

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal It can, but it needs `importrange("abcd123abcd123", "sheet1!A1:C10")` e.g., `=query(importrange("abcd123abcd123", "sheet1!A1:C10"))` ;-)