# Google Docs sheets: How to refer values in other column by key? (like SQL join)

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace

I have a sheet/document with item number and it's price.
In an invoice, I have:

```
| Number | Qty | Price | ... | Total price
| 21     | 3   |  ???  | ... | = C2 * B2
```

I'd like the Price column to be filled by looking up the value from other sheet or document, i.e. something like

```
=LOOKUP( PricesSheet, Column C, row with value from A2).
```

Basically, I want a SQL join functionality.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10391/how-do-i-lookup-a-value-from-another-sheet-in-google-docs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try something like:

```
=vlookup(A1,Sheet2!H:I,2,0)
```

where ColumnH in Sheet2 ('other sheet') contains `Number` and ColumnI of the same row the corresponding unit price.