# How to get data between tabs in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

is it possible to get a value from a tab cell and work with it in another tab?

```
Tab 1 (T1)
row  working hours (A)    who (B)
1    3                    Mike

-------------------------------

Tab 2 (T2)
row  price (A)
1    25€

-------------------------------

Tab 3 (T3)
total (A)
75€ =(T1.A*T2.A)
```

Comment: See also: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/786/how-do-i-link-a-cell-in-google-spreadsheets-to-a-cell-in-another-document/

Answer (score 1):

Found it on [Google Docs Support Forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Docs/thread?tid=562f767c7eabdda2&hl=en&search_impression_id=87a7e9412806adf3%3A12efc190ba4&search_source=related_question)

```
Tab 1 (T1)
row  working hours (A)    who (B)
1    3                    Mike

-------------------------------

Tab 2 (T2)
row  price (A)
1    25€

-------------------------------

Tab 3 (T3)
total (A)
75€ =('Tab 1'!A1*'Tab 2'!A1)
```