# How to SUM() a column from one Google Spreadsheets in another spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

Has anyone been able to return the `SUM()` result of a column in one Google Spreadsheets to a different spreadsheet?

I am trying the `ImportRange(key, criteria)` but I am not having any success. I am just bringing in the entire column and not the sum result.

Comment: Have you tried to sum that?

Comment: Frank, see http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/google-fu

Answer (score 4):

If you want to leave the data on the *IMPORT* sheet untouched, then you need to do this:

`=SUM(IMPORTRANGE("key","range"))`

This is a good post, here on Web Applications, about the `IMPORTRANGE` function: **[IMPORTRANGE](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/913/29140)**

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue yesterday. Solution was:

```
=SUM(IMPORTRANGE("SpreadsheetURL","SheetName!A1:A100"))
```

2 important notes:

1. You will initially see a `#REF!` error in your cell with a red color in the corner. You'll need to hover over it and allow access to the spreadsheets that you're referencing.
2. If any of the original data in the spreadsheet range you're referencing in `A1:A100` contain errors such as

```
#NULL!
#DIV/0!
#VALUE!
#REF!
#NAME?
#NUM!
#N/A
```

then your formula must be modified to include `SUMIF()` as follows

```
=SUMIF(IMPORTRANGE("SpreadsheetURL","SheetName!A1:A100"), ">0")
```

This ensures that it's only adding actual numbers and not error codes.

Answer (score 0):

`ImportRange(...)` is indeed the function you need to use. Here are the steps you need to follow:

1. At Spreadsheet 1 sum up the values you want to a specific cell (e.g. `A4`)
2. On the address bar of Spreadsheet 1 check for the key value (it's the long number that starts after key= and ends before #gid) - e.g. key=ABC -
3. At spreadsheet 2 go to the cell to which you need to present the sum and write `=ImportRange("key","SheetName!CellName")`, e.g. based on our example `=ImportRange("ABC","Sheet1!A4")`

You can also refer to this post [ImportRange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008661/linking-one-google-docs-spreadsheet-to-another)

Comment: BTW: I had to use =ImportRange("key";"SheetName!CellName") to make it work. (using a ";" instead of a ",") and it doesn't work yet with new google sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can **access a cell or a range from another google sheet** (i mean a **separate file**) using the the **`IMPORTRANGE`** function. Here is an example:

**`=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Aviydfsh6PygtPjphKc5Fnvnm8g_Xoedf6utNqp2Ql4A", "MySheetName!E107") + SUM(E4:E99)`**

Here we ***provide the url to the other sheet*** in the `IMPORTRANGE` function, fetches cell E107 from sheet named `MySheetName` and adds it with sum of range `E4:E99` in current sheet. While doing this you'll be **asked to allow current sheet to access the other sheet**.