# CONCATENATE inside IMPORTRANGE inside Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, importrange, concatenate

I found this formula:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("key","A:Z"),"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 WHERE Col1 contains 'value' ORDER BY Col1")
```

[here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43989/google-spreadsheet-importing-only-certain-rows) and I'd like to add a concatenate function where `value` is taken from cell (B1) for example.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

But first, bear in mind that `=CONCATENATE("a","b")` is the same as `="a"&"b"`, but shorter.

Example:

```
=QUERY(
IMPORTRANGE("key","A:Z"),
"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 WHERE Col1 contains '"&B1&"' ORDER BY Col1"
)
```

**References**
[CONCATENATE - Docs editor help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought it'd be a lot more convoluted...