# Importing specific rows within one document to another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, import

I found a similar question on your site.
[Importing only certain rows between spreadsheet documents](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43989/importing-only-certain-rows-between-spreadsheet-documents)

Is it possible to realize the same import within one document?

I have a table with a large number of rows on the first sheet. On the second sheet I need to import only those rows that contain a specific text in the 6th column.

I have tried to do it in a similar way.

```
=QUERY(ArrayFormula(General!B3:L2502), "SELECT * WHERE Col6 contains 'value' ORDER BY Col1")
```

But the miracle didn't happen...

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data range starts in column `B`. When the search keys are in column `F`, that is the fifth column rather than the sixth column.

To avoid the need to calculate the number of columns, use column labels in the `query()`, like this:

```
=query(General!B3:L, "where F contains 'value' order by B", 0)
```

Comment: It's working, thank you. Just one problem. When you selectively move lines like this, the hyperlink is lost. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: To keep hyperlinks, use `filter()` instead of `query()`. Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741). Post a [new question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) instead.