# Import Range on Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I want Cell D1 of this link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AupKcedJ0nhPdFFyMVhySWNvNzlYTV9RZ1FmYXdKc0E&usp=sharing#gid=2
To be imported to E9 of this link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AupKcedJ0nhPdFdwYWdlR0tCM293VEVUZXhhOTROQXc&usp=sharing#gid=3

This is the code that I used on E9 of the 2nd link:

```
=importrange("0AupKcedJ0nhPdFFyMVhySWNvNzlYTV9RZ1FmYXdKc0E&usp", "sheet2!E9:E9")
```

I'm already a viewer and collaborator of the 2 spreadsheets but I always get this error:

> The requested spreadsheet key, sheet title, or cell range was not found.

Answer (score 2):

You are grabbing too much of the spreadsheet key...Try this piece:

```
0AupKcedJ0nhPdFFyMVhySWNvNzlYTV9RZ1FmYXdKc0E
```

So your line should read:

```
=importrange("0AupKcedJ0nhPdFFyMVhySWNvNzlYTV9RZ1FmYXdKc0E","sheet2!E9:E9")
```

This **[answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/913/29140)** on Web Applications, explains the `IMPORTRANGE` in detail.