# How do I Import a Range from one Google Spreadsheet into another?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I am getting the same error as described [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/56669/import-range-on-google-spreadsheet) except not for the same reason.  I am using the new Google Sheets, so I am supposed to be able to paste the entire source URL into the sheet, like so:

```
=ImportRange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zRHatplJ6AVUSWr1HXoycUrvtK05dw4-ZqeEYN1xJ4Y/edit?usp=sharing", "B:B")
```

However, that results in the error:

> The requested spreadsheet key, sheet title, or cell range was not found.

I am the author of both sheets, so I see no reason for the error to occur.  Also, since I'm trying to get the data from the second column of the first sheet in the source, I shouldn't need to include the sheet name.  Nonetheless, I have tried it both with and without the sheet name, and got the same results.

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:** [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zRHatplJ6AVUSWr1HXoycUrvtK05dw4-ZqeEYN1xJ4Y/edit?usp=sharing) is the source sheet, and [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuonvFkia1zadGlXUjRQODNIQWhNd010LTQ5S2cxd2c&usp=sharing) is the destination sheet (in particular, the "Data" sheet).

Comment: Tried all kinds of different scenarios but wasn't able to reproduce the error. This it possible for you to share the two doc with us? Or throw in a screenshot?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I've added links to the sheets, which I have permitted access to for anyone with the link.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Sorry, got distracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only after having requested that the documents were to be shared with us, was I able to determine what's going on.

The response sheet is *new Google Sheet*  proof:
[image]

The sheet, in which you want to pull the data in, doesn't have this mark.

You are trying to import the data via the complete URL (new Sheets style) from within an old Google Spreadsheet. This is where Google says: *No Can Do !!*

If you use the key instead, it works just fine:

```
 =IMPORTRANGE("1zRHatplJ6AVUSWr1HXoycUrvtK05dw4-ZqeEYN1xJ4Y", "B:B")
```

See references for more information on this topic.

### References

- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/913/29140
- https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/74206/29140

Comment: Ah!  Brilliant!  Thanks for the extra set of eyes.  This was driving me insane!