# How to import cell data from one workbook to a different workbook?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

All answers I have reviewed say use IMPORTRANGE by referencing the "KEY=" in the URL of the source cell.  I find no "KEY=" in the source URL.  So I always receive a "parse error."

Comment: Related [Import Range on Google Spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/56946/88163)

Comment: Related [How do I link a cell in Google Spreadsheets to a cell in another document?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/786/88163)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the entire url:

`=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QDCf2MDkN7eopuTT-EieQI39Bpc_Y6D-3EWefimpk/edit#gid=0", "A:A")`

But just the spreadsheet id should also work:

`=IMPORTRANGE("1QDCf2MDkN7eopuTT-EieQI39Bpc_Y6D-3EWefimpk", "A:A")`

More generally the google sheets url is structured like this:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/spreadsheetId/edit#gid=sheetId`

*The spreadsheet id's used in this answer don't exist and are only included as examples.*

[Documentation Spreadsheet id](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#spreadsheet_id)

[Documentation importrange](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks.  I had been omitting the quotation marks.  The link is now working.  Problem solved.