# CONTINUE function is annoying me?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I am trying to pull data from other Google spreadsheets into specific cells on my current sheet by using the `IMPORTRANGE` function.  It's working well in some cells, but it others, it keeps getting the `CONTINUE` function.  It's automatically placing that function in the cell and will not let me overwrite it with the `IMPORTRANGE` function.

I have tried clearing all the data, I removed the entire column and tried to start over, I've tried copy/pasting the function I want into the cell and nothing is working. Has anyone else had this happen?  It's pulling data from cells above the one that I want the `IMPORTRANGE` function which would be lovely in some cases, just not what I need!

I'm pretty new to Google spreadsheets so I am hoping there is just something simple I am not doing.

Comment: Is it possible to share the doc with us, Erika?

Answer (score 1):

The `IMPORTRANGE` function returns a predefined range, using the following syntax:

```
IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_key, range_string)
```

The *string range* is exactly that what's being returned. If it is `B1:B5` in the other spreadsheet, then it will return those cells, starting from `A1` in the current sheet. Copy/pasting the exact formula in the current spreadsheet should/must give the same result over and over.

If the behaviour of the `IMPORTRANGE` function start to annoy you, then it's time to evaluate. Here are a few options:

1. Take a deep breath, count to ten and make some coffee.
2. Is the *string range* still the same?
3. Did I change the other spreadsheet in the meantime?
4. Do I really want this result and not a `COUNT` or a `SUM`?
5. Is another formula interfering?

It's also wise to read up (perhaps again) on this post here on Web Applications.

### References

- [IMPORTRANGE, web applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/913/29140)
- [IMPORTRANGE, Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093340?hl=en)