# Google Spreadsheets and Zapier

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace, zapier

My client has a WordPress site that uses Gravity forms. I'm using Zapier so that each time a new submission is entered into the form, it adds this information as a new row in a Google Spreadsheets (`Master Sheet`).

Everything is working, but from there this data gets pulled into a second Google Spreadsheet (`Client Sheet`) but new entries in the `Master Sheet` are not picked up by the `Client Sheet` unless there is some form of human action on the `Master Sheet`. In other words, I need to effect the `Master Sheet` before the entries get pulled across to the `Client Sheet`. However, if I manually add an entry to the `Master Sheet`, it immediately reflects on the `Client Sheet`.

So my guess is that there is some kind of edit function that gets triggered by a human user but not by an entry from Zapier.

Any ideas?

PS. I have already tried using the script detailed in this question:
[How can I get Google Sheets to auto-update a reference to another sheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60324/how-can-i-get-google-sheets-to-auto-update-a-reference-to-another-sheet)
Unfortunately I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how you're pulling in the Master Sheet info to the Client Sheet, but to help with some background, when your zap adds a new row to a spreadsheet, it's literally creating a new row and filling that new row with data.  This can impact how that data can be automatically retrieved depending on the details of the formulas, scripts, etc you're using to pull that data into the Client sheet.

If you like, you can ping us at contact@zapier.com and we can check on the zap itself to make sure there's nothing that seems out of place on that front.  Happy to lend a hand!