# Make a summary admin document

Tags: google-sheets

I trying to make an admin document where all rows from other documents are added automatically.

Example:
Person A is typing data into this document
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1piyeJWfr6oTkhwh-1mm8KiS4yB8uclDV2O_BG5przgg/edit#gid=0

Person B is typing data into a similar document

Admin is watching everything that has been typed by Person A and B in one overall summary document.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KIDShE_fvaO_9iP5xb0ax1v7LtGdrIU1ksou0IwEibA/edit#gid=0

Is this possible? And how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but not in real-time, as it could possible if they were typing/viewing in the same document and screen area.

Use `IMPORTRANGE()` function to get the data from each spreadsheet and arrays to properly join.

I.E.

In the admin spreadsheet, in the A1 add the following formula to get the column titles from the Test spreadsheet 1.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1piyeJWfr6oTkhwh-1mm8KiS4yB8uclDV2O_BG5przgg","Ark1!A1:H1")
```

In the admin spreadsheet, in the A2 cell add a formula like the following one to add the data from two spreadsheets

```
=QUERY(
{IMPORTRANGE("1piyeJWfr6oTkhwh-1mm8KiS4yB8uclDV2O_BG5przgg","Ark1!A2:H");
IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_key,"Ark1!A2:H")},
"Select * Where Col1 is not null")
```

Instead of spreasheet_key you should use the spreadsheet key of the second spreadsheet.

There is a question in this site regarding the refresh of data taken from another spreadsheet:

[How can I get Google Sheets to auto-update a reference to another sheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60324/how-can-i-get-google-sheets-to-auto-update-a-reference-to-another-sheet)

**References**

- [IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)
- [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)

Comment: (Never mind the previous comment): I'll just state here that `Col1 is not null` is also an option for the same condition.

Comment: @NormalHuman: After reading your comment I remembered that `* ` could be used instead of listing all the columns, so I updated the select parameter and included the criteria in your comment as it looks better.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for taking you time to answer me.

I've tried the suggested formula - but it doesn't work? Can you see that I do wrong?