# Auto-Import Master Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm fairly new to Google Spreadsheets and completely useless when it comes to functions and formulas.

Is there a way to take info from multiple sheets within a workbook and compile them into a master sheet within that same workbook?
If so, is there then a way to have any changes on the original sheet then be reflected in the master sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with `importrange`, details here:

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340

Comment: Or have a look at this answer, here on Web Applications: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/913/29140