# Lookup/Copy data from different sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I am creating a schedule sheet in Google Spreadsheets that will have a number of different people inputting their own information. I would like the Director to be able to open a single document that "gets" each of the employee's sheets and compiles into one document. Is that possible with Google Spreadsheets?

I am currently setting this up so am flexible, for instance whether all employees enter into the one document or each has their own. My plan was for each employee to have their own sheet and also have one document containing a copy of each of these individual sheets.  i.e. Single sheet for each employee (of which there are 5) in separate documents along with one document containing 5 sheets (one for each of the employees).

Comment: I am currently setting it up, so it could be either. My plan was to have one sheet per employee, then one doc that included each persons sheet. i.e.) Single page for each employee (5 employees) and one workbook that included 5 sheets (one for each of the employees)

Comment: See this post here on Web Applications for a detailed description: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/786/29140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plans seem sensible to me and I think reasonably straightforward to implement. A formula such as:

```
=importrange("1NsEAt1biV822J4RnqOmb4MW6GCjrkUzfZjbssnZmkSQ)","Sheet1!A1:F8")
```

in each of the employee sheets in the Director's cut should import Sheet1!A1:F8 from each individual employee's document (once access has been granted). The long string of characters in the middle of the above formula is the 'key' and is unique to each document.

When all the relevant details are in the Director's copy it should then also be quite easy to process them further for analysis purposes.

Comment: I, literally, was just doing this. Looks like this will be perfect!! Thank you sooo much, I appreciate it!