# IF THEN Google Sheets - referencing different workbook

Tags: google-sheets, if-this-then-that

I'm hoping to do the following:

Spreadsheet 1, cell A1: pull in data from cell A1 in Spreadsheet 2, but ONLY if cell B1 contains exact text of "partner". Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I link a cell in Google Spreadsheets to a cell in another document?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/786/how-do-i-link-a-cell-in-google-spreadsheets-to-a-cell-in-another-document)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`=if(B1="partner",importrange("<insert the url for spreadsheeth#2>","wa_13682302!A1"),"")`

You need to combine:

- `IMPORTRANGE`: to get the value of Cell A1 from Spreadsheet#2 [doc ref](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340)
- `IF`: to create an expression to test the value in cell B1, and then return values based on whether the expression is true or false. [doc ref](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)